# animation in javaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a project that has to do with animation in javaFx, I wrote the GUI for it and it is a Stick Figure. I am trying to make the stick figure walk to the right side of the pane and then when it touches the right side turn and go back the other way all the way to the left wall of the pane. I have this code that is a moving ball that does exactly what I want for my stick figure to do but I cannot seem to modify that code into my stick figure program. any ideas on how to do this? both codes are below:

```
    package animationdemo;

    import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
    import javafx.animation.Timeline;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.util.Duration;

    public class MovingBallDemo_3 extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    BallPane ballPane = new BallPane(); // Create a ball pane
    // Pause and resume animation
    ballPane.setOnMousePressed(e -> ballPane.pause());
    ballPane.setOnMouseReleased(e -> ballPane.play());
    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(ballPane, 250, 150);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Bouncing Ball Control"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}

 class BallPane extends Pane {

public final double radius = 20;
private double x = 2 * radius, y = 3 * radius;
private double dx = 3; // Number of pixels to move each time
private Circle circle = new Circle(x, y, radius);
private Timeline animation;

public BallPane() {
    circle.setFill(Color.RED); // Set ball color
    getChildren().add(circle); // Place a ball into this pane
    // Create the animation for 25 millisecond events
    animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(25), e -> moveBall()));
    animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    animation.play(); // Start animation
}

public void play() {
    animation.play();
}

public void pause() {
    animation.pause();
}
// Move the ball. When a wall is encountered, reverse direction
protected void moveBall() {
    if (x <= radius || x >= getWidth() - radius) {
        dx *= -1; // Change direction
    }
    // Adjust ball position
    x += dx;
    circle.setCenterX(x);
}
}
```

the above is the animation that I want the stick figure GUI to do. here is my attempt of merging my code in with the code above to make the stick figure work but nothing happens:

```
     package Stickfigure;

     import java.awt.Graphics;
     import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
     import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
     import javafx.animation.Timeline;
     import javafx.application.Application;
     import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
     import javafx.event.EventHandler;
     import javafx.scene.Scene;
     import javafx.scene.control.Button;
     import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
     import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
     import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
     import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
     import javafx.scene.shape.ArcType;
     import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
     import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
     import javafx.stage.Stage;
     import javafx.util.Duration;


     public class Stickfigure extends Application {

      @Override
     public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      BallPane ballPane = new BallPane();
      ballPane.setOnMousePressed(e -> ballPane.pause());
      ballPane.setOnMouseReleased(e -> ballPane.play());

    Circle circle = new Circle(100, 100, 0);//head
    Circle circle1 = new Circle(120, 80, 50);//eye
    circle1.setRadius(5);//radius of eye
    circle.setRadius(50);//radius of head
    circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);//circle color
    circle1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);//circle color
    circle.setFill(null);//makes the head empty(no brain haha)
    circle.setStrokeWidth(5);//sets the line thickness of circle (head)

    Arc arc = new Arc();//mouth
    arc.setCenterX(110.0f);//mouth position
    arc.setCenterY(120.0f);//mouth position
    arc.setRadiusX(35.0f);//mouth size
    arc.setRadiusY(25.0f);//mouth size
    arc.setStartAngle(1.0f);//angle of mouth
    arc.setLength(5.0f);//length of mouth
    arc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);

    Line line1 = new Line(100, 250, 100, 150); //body of stick figure
    Line line2 = new Line(); //left leg
    Line line3 = new Line();//right leg
    Line line4 = new Line();//right arm
    Line line5 = new Line();//left arm

    line2.setStartX(30.0f); //left leg starting position y
    line2.setStartY(350.0f);//left leg starting position y
    line2.setEndX(100.0f);//left leg end pos x
    line2.setEndY(250.0f);//left leg end pos y

    line3.setStartX(200.0f); //right leg start pos x
    line3.setStartY(350.0f);// right leg start pos y
    line3.setEndX(100.0f); //right leg end pos x
    line3.setEndY(250.0f); //right leg end pos y

    line4.setStartX(100.0f);//right arm start pos x
    line4.setStartY(200.0f); //right arm start pos y
    line4.setEndX(200.0f); //right arm end pos x
    line4.setEndY(170.0f); //right arm end pos y

    line5.setStartX(30.0f);//left arm arm statt pos x
    line5.setStartY(250.0f); // left arm start pos y
    line5.setEndX(100.0f);//left arm end pos x
    line5.setEndY(200.0f);//left arm end pos y

    line1.setStrokeWidth(5); //thickness of line
    line1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);//color of line
    line2.setStrokeWidth(5);//thickness of line
    line2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);//color of line
    line3.setStrokeWidth(5);//thickness of line
    line3.setStroke(Color.BLACK);//color of line
    line4.setStrokeWidth(5);//thickness of line
    line4.setStroke(Color.BLACK);//color of line
    line5.setStrokeWidth(5);//thickness of line
    line5.setStroke(Color.BLACK);//color of line

    // Create a pane to hold the circle 

    ballPane.getChildren().add(circle); //adds circle to picture
     ballPane.getChildren().add(circle1);//adds circle to picture
    ballPane.getChildren().add(line1);//adds line
    ballPane.getChildren().add(line2);//adds line
    ballPane.getChildren().add(line3);//adds line
   ballPane.getChildren().add(line4);//adds line
    ballPane.getChildren().add(line5);//adds line
    ballPane.getChildren().add(arc);//adds arc





    Scene scene = new Scene( ballPane, 400, 400);

    primaryStage.setTitle("stick figure");//title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
class BallPane extends Pane {

public final double radius = 20;
private double x = 2 * radius, y = 3 * radius;
private double dx = 3; // Number of pixels to move each time

private Timeline animation;

public BallPane() {


    // Create the animation for 25 millisecond events
    animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(25), e ->    moveBall()));
    animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    animation.play(); // Start animation
}

public void play() {
    animation.play();
}

public void pause() {
    animation.pause();
}
// Move the ball. When a wall is encountered, reverse direction
protected void moveBall() {
    if (x <= radius || x >= getWidth() - radius) {
        dx *= -1; // Change direction
    }
    // Adjust ball position
    x += dx;

}
}

}
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to move anything? All your animation does is change the value of `x`.

Comment: @James_D how can I get the whole thing stick figure to move?

Comment: Put some code in the handler for the animation that changes the position of the thing you want to move.

Comment: @James_D how can I get all pieces of the stick figure to move all together?

Comment: See previous comment

Comment: @James_D I can see the previous comment but "put some code in the handler for the animation that changes the postion of the stick figure" doesn't explain to me how to make all pieces move. can you provide an example so I can better understand it.

Comment: I'm not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: Sorry if it's not helpful, but what do you actually expect here? Your original question was "Here's an example that animates a circle, here's my attempt to generalize it to animate something else, why doesn't my attempt do anything". The answer, which I gave in the first comment, is that the example you quoted has code that changes the location of the circle. The code you wrote has no code that changes the location of your figure. So just add some code to change the location of the figure, there are lots of ways you can do that. This is not a free code service.

Comment: its okay just trying to learn javafx and thought this was a place that helped but maybe someone else on here can that knows what they are doing, cause obviously you either don't want to help me for no reason or you just don't know how. :) thanks bro @jam

Comment: Here's the problem I have with your question: A couple of comments back, you said "can you provide an example so I can better understand it". You have already posted a perfectly good example. Your code doesn't work because you haven't followed that example closely enough (e.g. in the example, the shape is a property of the `BallPanel`, and - as I pointed out - the `moveBall` method changes the location of the shape: in your code you don't do that). So the problem really is that you don't seem to understand the example you posted. No-one can understand it for you.

Comment: So what's needed here is for you to go and study that example, read the code, figure out what it does, look at the documentation for any methods if you don't understand what they do and how they work, etc. (All the usual things programmers do when they look at existing code.) This forum is not really designed for questions like this. If someone does provide the code to make your example work, it won't help you understand it any more than the example you already posted, so it's really not clear what worth it would be to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing any moving in the moveBall() method. You just change local values. Have a look at the [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) class from which Pane is inheriting and the [translateXProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#translateXProperty). You want to change that, not just your fields.
You even had the actual translation in your Ball class: `circle.setCenterX(x);`

```
protected void moveBall() {
    if (x <= radius || x >= getWidth() - radius) {
        dx *= -1; // Change direction
    }
    // Adjust ball position
    x += dx; 

    //#######################################
    setTranslateX(x); // Move the Pane!!! ###
    //#######################################
}
```